# How to hide drawable right programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I am setting drawable right for EditText like below,

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp), null);
```

I am setting drawable left for EditText in xml. I want to set it's visibility to visible or hide.How Do I do that programmatically.

I have EditText for Search. While start typing I am setting clear icon programatically.

Clear icon will clear text in EditText. When clear icon without text is clicked I want to close keyboard and make clear icon hide.
Below is my code for that,

```
 editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
                    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp), null);
                }
            });
            editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        if(editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2]!=null){
                            if(event.getX() >= (editText.getRight()- editText.getLeft() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width())) {

                                if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                                    editText.setText("");
                                }
                                else {

                                   // getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                                     //       WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                                    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                                    closeKeyboard();
                                    editText.setCursorVisible(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I want to hide it programmatically.

Comment: have you tried setting up `null` to clear at same location?

Comment: this would not work because in onClick you are setting drawable again. Also in onTouch you have returned false so onClicked will be called.

Comment: @ShadowDroid what I want to achieve is, After typing text for search using clear icon I can able to clear text. I also want to close the search by closing keyboard and changing visibility of drawables when the clear icon is clicked with empty EditText

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly change your `onTouchListener` as below. Instead of looking to capture `ACTION_UP` go for `ACTION_DOWN` as it will be called first in `onTouch` from there will `return true` as now we do not need to go `onClick` upon closing keyboard.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        if(editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2]!=null){
                            if(event.getX() >= (editText.getRight()- editText.getLeft() - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[2].getBounds().width())) {

                                if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                                    editText.setText("");
                                }
                                else {

                                   // getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                                     //       WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                                    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
                                    closeKeyboard();
                                    editText.setCursorVisible(false);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you its wrking now. But now I am facing different problem.

Comment: @Kousalya  May I what problem has been induced due to this solution?

Comment: No no its not like that....Not due to that solution..I am closing the keyboard when clear icon is clicked after that opening again when EditText is clicked. My keyboard is opening only at the second click. I dont know why..

Answer (score 5):

Just pass `null` in `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` method to  hide  Drawable from your `editText`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: @Kousalya try to pass `0` instead of `null`

Comment: @Kousalya and @NileshRathod null is working fine I just tried. You just need to do `editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null)`. Kindly ensure you are not reloading layout again?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Null the right drawable

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
```

Here 3rd parameter is right drawable.

Or you can use

```
editText.setCompoundDrawables(null,null, null, null);
```

Heare

setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom)